# Почему здесь стоит запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Почему в предложении перед "их" стоит запятая?

> Это "перспективные таланты", их рекомендовали наши тренеры.

Answer (score 2):

1. Да, запятая действительно стоит:

***Это "перспективные таланты", их рекомендовали наши тренеры.***

Но почему бы ей там не стоять? Это бессоюзное сложное предложение (БСП) с двумя грамматическими основами.

Вторая часть продолжает тему первой части и содержит дополнительную информацию: это перспективные кадры по мнению тренеров.

2. Особой необходимости в более сильных знаках (двоеточие или тире) нет, но вместо запятой можно поставить присоединительное тире с тем же пояснительным значением, обозначив **увеличенную паузу:**

***Это "перспективные таланты" — их рекомендовали наши тренеры.***